# Why is my XNA game lagging?

Tags: c#, xna

The code worked beautifully before we saved it to try and submit it for our programming class. We believe we have a memory leak of some kind, but can't spot it. We made no changes to the code before saving it and before the save all was well, so something went wrong when we saved it. Below is all the code in our update method. We have a case for each difficulty inside our update method, which is where we believe the problem lies.

```
//Easy game mode
        case GameState.Easy:
            //starts backgound music
            MediaPlayer.Play(BackgroundMusic);
            this.IsMouseVisible = false;
            PlayerTwoSpeed = 5;

            if (HitCount == PointsToWin) PlayerOneWins();
            if (HitCountEnemy == PointsToWin) PlayerTwoWins();

            //getting the keyboard state, so input can be detected
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
            {
                if (POPBox.Y >= 373)
                {
                    POPBox.Y += 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    POPBox.Y += PlayersSpeed;
                }
            }

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
            {
                if (POPBox.Y <= 0)
                {
                    POPBox.Y += 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    POPBox.Y += -PlayersSpeed;
                }
            }
            // Ball limits

            if (BallBox.Y <= 0)
                VelocityY *= -1;
            if (BallBox.Y >= 463)
                VelocityY *= -1;

            //Collision Detection (Runs this code if it hits the player one's paddle)
            if (BallBox.Intersects(POPBox))
            {
                //Used to deflect in different directions for some veriety
                if (PlayersSpeed > 0)
                    VelocityY += 3;
                if (PlayersSpeed < 0)
                    VelocityY -= 3;
                VelocityX *= -1;
                ShockerGenerator();

                //Stopping the no slope bug. If it wants to bounce perfectly straight, it is slightly shifty to fix that error.

                if (VelocityY == 0)
                    VelocityY = VelocityY += 3;
                if (VelocityX == 0)
                    VelocityX = VelocityX += 3;

                //speed control

                if (VelocityX > 10)
                    VelocityX = 10;
                if (VelocityY > 10)
                    VelocityY = 10;
            }
            // Runs this code if the ball hits player two's paddle
            if (BallBox.Intersects(PTPBox))
            {
                VelocityX *= -1;
                if (VelocityY == 0)
                    VelocityY = VelocityY += 3;
                if (VelocityX == 0)
                    VelocityX = VelocityX += 3;
            }


            //Object a collision

            if (BallBox.Intersects(ShocObjectARectangle))
            {
                VelocityY *= -1;
            }
            if (BallBox.Intersects(ShocObjectBRectangle))
            {
                VelocityX *= -1;
            }


            // If Player One Loses

            if (BallBox.X >= 790)
            {
                PlayerOneLoses();
            }


            if (BallBox.X <= 0)
            {
                PlayerTwoLoses();

            }



            //Player Two's "AI" and limits

            if ((PTPBox.Y + 50) > BallBox.Y)
                PTPBox.Y += -PlayerTwoSpeed;
            if ((PTPBox.Y + 50) < BallBox.Y)
                PTPBox.Y += PlayerTwoSpeed;



            //Object A movement code

            ShocObjectARectangle.X += ObjectASpeed;
            if (ShocObjectARectangle.X <= 80)
                ObjectASpeed *= -1;
            else if (ShocObjectARectangle.X >= 600)
                ObjectASpeed *= -1;


            //Object B movement code

            ShocObjectBRectangle.Y += ObjectBSpeed;
            if (ShocObjectBRectangle.Y <= 0)
                ObjectBSpeed *= -1;
            else if (ShocObjectBRectangle.Y >= 415)
                ObjectBSpeed *= -1;


            // Ball Velocity

            BallBox.Y += -VelocityY;
            BallBox.X += VelocityX;
            break;
```

Comment: Shorten down the code to only the relevant parts please...

Comment: I have no idea where the memory leak would be. I assume it's in one of the cases. We've edited the main post to include only one case

Comment: what do you mean by "saved" it?

Comment: That is one long case.

Comment: We clicked file and then selected save all as and saved it to our school's tech share drive. This broke not only the solution on the tech share, but also the solution we had on our C drive which was flawless before saving. (By flawless I mean it didn't lag.)

Comment: @DB so you saved the solution, not the game state

Comment: Yes. That's what we did.

Comment: Use a profiler, it's the best way.

Comment: @DB It might be because you continually queue up songs in your MediaPlayer on every update tick:  MediaPlayer.Play(BackgroundMusic);

Comment: @DB posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It appears you are continually queueing up songs in your MediaPlayer on every update tick:

You will want to move this outside of your update() method

```
MediaPlayer.Play(BackgroundMusic);
```